# How to make toolbar item show in only certain pages

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

You will be able to tell from the code below that the current visuals of the app will be a little something like this:

The New toolbar item on top and the tabbed pages below. And regardless of which page I tab too the toolbar still stays on top. I want the toolbar to be visible only in the first page. Is this even possible? I can't put in inside StackLayout.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_101"
             x:Class="Test_101.MainPage">
    <ContentPage Title="Main">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem Text="New" Order="Primary"/>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar Placeholder="Search..." TextChanged="SearchBar_OnTextChanged"/>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="ListView_OnRefreshing">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding FName}" Detail="{Binding Skill, StringFormat='Skill: {0}'}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <local:Tryouts Title="Tryouts"/>
    <local:Credits Title="Credits"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Did you run the app on iOS or Android?

Comment: I ran the app on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove those icons which you don't want on that page from the toolbar by using the following lines of code, add this inside your constructor or onResume method

```
int position = 0;     //Add your icon position
ToolbarItems.RemoveAt(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t set the ToolBar as hidden directly.Because the contentPage is in RootViewController and Xamarin.forms dosen’t provide such a method.

So ,I suggest that you can create Custom Renderers. Then set this property in both iOS and Android . About how to use Custom Renderers, you can refer to the link : [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

For example

### in iOS:

```
...
using xxx;(your forms's namespace)
using xxx.iOS;
...
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Tryouts),typeof(Tryouts_iOS))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class Tryouts_iOS:PageRenderer
    {
      public Tryouts_iOS()
      {

      }

      public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
      {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden=true;
      }

      public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
      {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = false;
      }

    }
}
```